# Understanding gradle multi project build.gradle execution order

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm doing some experiments on below gradle multi project structure

[image]

I have added println in all the build.gradle & settings.gradle files to see in what order they execute. I'm seeing that projectA -> build.gradle file is executing after its subproject pA1->build.gradle as seen in the output below

[image]

I'm not understanding why projectA->build.gradle is executing after its sub projects ? Should it not execute before its subproject, just like the build.gradle file on root.

location on project [Multi project sample](https://github.com/p-sharma/gradle-multi-proj-sample)

Answer (score 0):

First off, putting a naked `println` line in your build.gradle files does not give you execution order. The `println` will be invoked in the configuration phase, so if anything you're looking at the configuration order.

If you want to investigate execution order add a task with the same name to all your build.gradle files, maybe something like this:

```
task action << {
    println("In project: ${project.name}")
}
```

and then run `gradle action` from the root folder.

Comment: Sp I added the above snippet in project in allproject block in root project. When i execute it i see output like this http://imgur.com/RCKhbZY. Also, during configuration phase, why would child sub-module will configure before parent ? Shouldn't parent be configured before child.